# SharePoint Admin Roles

Tags: office-365, administration, sharepoint-admin-center, global-administrator

Is it possible to restrict a SharePoint Admin service account to perform limited set of actions in the tenant. IT is not keen to provide Admin role outside IT, but ready to do it if somehow access can be restricted.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Microsoft created admin roles cannot be altered, nor can you create your own custom admin roles to perform specific actions at a tenant level.

You could potentially use the Graph API with an Application permission scope to perform a specific operation without the end user holding any specific admin role. If you can post a question with what specific operation(s) you need a non-admin to perform, someone may be able to help guide you in the correct direction.

Comment: We need developers/ support staff to give some specific access like to connect to SPO in PowerShell, develop and deploy PnP templates, manage SharePoint sites etc